# Is it possible to define a React uncontrolled functional component (without class)?

Tags: reactjs

A checkbox such as the one below triggers the dreaded **"Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled"** warning

```
const Checkbox = props =>
  <label className="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} defaultChecked={false}/>
 </label>
```

All examples of uncontrolled components use the classed based approach for defining components, and I have found none that used functional component.

Is it possible at all to define an uncontrolled component defined with a function ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my second approach:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-glitter-7nxy5?file=/src/App.js:0-1090

I don't think this is how I would design a component, but it is basically what you are asking for. A component that doesn't use the onChange-binding but instead uses `useRef` and updates the checkbox that way.

```
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [checked2, setChecked2] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Usecase #1</h2>
      <div>currently: {checked ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      <button onClick={e => setChecked(!checked)}>toggle</button>
      <Checkbox checked={checked} setChecked={setChecked} />

      <hr />
      <h2>Usecase #2</h2>
      <div>currently: {checked2 ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      <button onClick={e => setChecked2(!checked2)}>toggle</button>
      <Checkbox checked={checked2} setChecked={setChecked2} />

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const Checkbox = ({ checked, setChecked }) => {
  const checkboxRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update from props
    checkboxRef.current.checked = checked;

    const handleChange = event => setChecked(event.target.checked);
    // Update parent from change event
    checkboxRef.current.addEventListener("change", handleChange);

    // Cleanup
    return checkboxRef.current.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
  }, [checked, setChecked]);

  return (
    <label className="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ref={checkboxRef} />
    </label>
  );
};
```

Comment: The cleanup code won't work since you're defining a new arrow function as the handler to be removed. Define the handler once, and used it in both registering and unregistering of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `checked` and it will become uncontrolled:

```
const Checkbox = props =>
  <label className="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={false}/>
 </label>
```

When you add `checked`, React also expects `onChange`. It's either both for controlled, or none for uncontrolled

Comment: The problem is that I want to change the checked value externally and passed via props, i.e. not as a result of the checkbox being clicked but some external event

Comment: So you need a controlled component, and you must provide an `onChange` event handler

Comment: You want a half controlled element and this is exactly what React is complaining about

Answer (score 0):

You can just have an empty onChange:

```
const Checkbox = props => (
  <label className="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} onChange={() => void 0} />
  </label>
);
```

Comment: That's a controlled component, he is asking for an uncontrolled one